# definition from mathematics translated in english language

Tags: terminology

guys this question is more specific  related to english and math   together then  math only,i  am  studying  GRE  tasks(quantity  variant) and want to be  acquainted every term and trick  related to math problem,for example,let's take this task:

Each employee of a certain company is in either Department X or Department Y, and there are more than twice as many employees in Department X as in Department Y. The average (arithmetic mean) salary is $25,000$ for the employees in Department X and $35,000$ for the employees in Department Y. Which of the following amounts could be the average salary for all of the employees of the company?

i have question related to   this fragment from  problem: there are more then twice as many employees in department X as in department Y.
so  there is two way  to  translate this stattment  into mathematics  term.first:if in department X  there is $a$ person,then in $Y$ department there is $2*a$ employee,second variant is this ,first leave as  we introduced,but in $Y$ department  there is $a+2*a=3*a$ employee,which one is correct   one?it is very crucial  for  passing test successfuly,so i need to be clarified in such terms,thanks a  lot of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ denote the number of employees in $X$ and $b$ the number for $Y$.
Your attempt was to set $b=2a$, but that translates as *"In department $Y$ there are exactly twice as many employees as in department $X$". So there are two things wrong: You swapped the role of $X$ and $Y$ and you replaced "more than " by "exactly".
The correct tranlation of the given condition about employee counts is
$$a>2b.$$
This *might* mean that $a=3b$ or $a=100b$ or just that $a=2b+1$.

Note that I didn't write $a\ge 2b$ because that would be the translation for "at least twice as many", while the problem statement says "more than twice as many".

Comment: this is why i have posted question,because  sometimes it is difficult  exactly what is written   to understand,now it is clear,i will try  to  solve this problem and  if any question,i will post here now only for mathemaical solutions,thanks a lot of

Comment: by the  way,total number of employees would be $a+b$ right?